# Sort by column index not column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting

I have a select statement that is dynamic and having the ability to sort by column index rather than by name would make my life easier.

Example:

```
select id, name, description 
from table 
order by description
```

Would like something like:

```
select id, name, description 
from table 
order by colindex(2)
```

Comment: I would caution ordering by ordinal position. It still currently works in sql server but it was removed from the standards in ANSI-99. Not to mention that is you are using a ranking function like ROW_NUMBER you can't use the ordinal position in the order by there.

Comment: ordinal works fine it I thought it was not working because it turns out is not zero index based.

Comment: I understand the implications but it would be under a controlled environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

```
select id, name, description 
from table 
order by 2
```

Sometimes it is the easiest way specially when you are working on dynamic SQL. 
But, as mentioned in comments, try to avoid using column index. I think they are going to remove it as it is bug pron.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as correct and then avoided :)

Comment: I added more wording. Sometimes avoiding that might be very hard. Anyway, is someone uses a feature and s/he knows the risk, that up to him/her. I think it would last at least for next 10 year.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me. It did not sort at all. Do I have to specify the asc and desc hints with this?

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. Maybe I missed something I'll check again when I am near a computer. Maybe it is something as dumb as it is not zero index based.

Comment: yip is it not zero based lol The ORDER BY position number 0 is out of range of the number of items in the select list.

Comment: @CodeMilian, Right, it starts from 1. also if you have a number more numbers of columns, you'll get error. Assume you have 10 fields but in order by you specify 11. SQL will not ignore it and will return error.

Answer (score -1):

If you're building your SQL dynamically then store the column names in an array. That way you can build your order-by statement with an ordinal index and emit the real name of the column in the statement.